# Incrementar uma string numérica em 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou querendo somar 1 a um contador que está representado como uma string. o objetivo é obter a sequência de números posterior. Por exemplo: de 000570370 para 000570371.

parte do código:

```
 def rangeOrdemServ(self):
        db = self.conexaoBanco()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT ordem_serv_num FROM ordem_serv ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        dadosOrdemServ = cursor.fetchone()
        db.commit()
        global rec
        dados1 = [dadosOrdemServ]
        dados2 = [1]
        dados3 = (dados1) + (dados2)

        self.entrOrdServ.insert(END,dados3)
```

quando eu executo esse código obtenho a seguinte resposta:
`[('000005703701021',), 1]`, e não a esperada `000005703701022`

Comment: Por que os colchetes?

Comment: sem os coLchetes da o seguinte erro:     'dados3 = dados1 + dados2
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple'

Comment: `dadosOrdemServ` é uma String. Você quer tratá-la como um número para somar 1? É isso? Porque, se for, isso não tem nada a ver com concatenação.

Comment: sim é isso, trabalho a pouco tempo com python, nao tenho muita experiencia, pode me ajudar com essa questao?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use essa função:

```
def incrementarStringNumericaEmUm(stringNumerica):

    qtdDigitosComZeros = len(stringNumerica)
    originalComoNumero = int(stringNumerica)
    qtdDigitosSemZeros = len(str(originalComoNumero))
    resultadoComoNumero = originalComoNumero + 1

    qtdZerosNaOriginal = qtdDigitosComZeros - qtdDigitosSemZeros


    if len(str(resultadoComoNumero)) == qtdDigitosSemZeros:
        # Não houve "vai um"
        return ('0' * qtdZerosNaOriginal) + str(resultadoComoNumero)
    else:
        # Aumentou um dígito no resultado, então precisamos colocar um zero a menos
        return ('0' * (qtdZerosNaOriginal - 1)) + str(resultadoComoNumero)
```

Ela recebe uma string numérica no formato que você tem em `dadosOrdemServ` e retorna uma string numérica com o valor incrementado em um. Pra isso ela conta quantos zeros tem na original, depois converte a original para um número inteiro, incrementa esse número em um, transforma esse número em string e concatena de volta os zeros, tomando o cuidado de colocar um zero a menos em caso de "vai um".

Comment: deu esse erro:  originalComoNumero = int(dados)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Não é pra passar `dados`, mas sim `dadosOrdemServ`.

Comment: deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Dê um print em dadosOrdemServ e me diga o que sai.

Comment: Pelo que estou vendo, dadosOrdemServ é uma tupla. passe `dadosOrdemServ[0]` para a função, então.

Comment: quando dou um print sai: ('000005703701021',)

Comment: Passe `dadosOrdemServ[0]` para a função, então.

Comment: não deu nenhum erro agora mas não deu nenhum print tambem, onde eu recupero a resposta

Comment: A resposta é o retorno da função. Tipo: `numeroIncrementado = incrementarStringNumericaEmUm(dadosOrdemServ[0])`

Comment: no meu caso a resposta eu preciso que seja inserido dentro de uma entry, ex: self.entrOrdServ.insert(END,resposta)

Comment: Use o valor retornado pela função para fazer a inserção. Se está tendo problemas ao inserir algo no banco, isso seria assunto pra outra pergunta.

Comment: deu certo eu usei o resultadoComoNumero para inserir a reposta e ele da a sequência certinha, obrg pela força

Comment: Tranquilo. Bom trabalho.